# Create a chart with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a graph from a table that has a mask of values ​​and I don't know how to get someone can help? For example, if you put 1, it puts 1/5 and the / is a special bar. For the graph I need to get the value behind the mask.

[image: sheet - MOCA]
[image: sheet - Descrição]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

selectedNa = Target.Value
If Target.Row = 5 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Descrição").Range("ClassVEE"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        vee = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Descrição").Range("ClassVEE"), 1, False)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MOCA").Cells(17, Target.Column).Value = (vee + n + md + tas + s + rf + fvf + a + ed + o)
        Target.Value = selectedNum
    End If
End If

If Target.Row = 6 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Descrição").Range("ClassN"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
        n = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Descrição").Range("ClassN"), 1, False)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MOCA").Cells(17, Target.Column).Value = (vee + n + md + tas + s + rf + fvf + a + ed + o)
        Target.Value = selectedNum
    End If
End If
...
```

Comment: What about the other cells in the range, which do not respect the described pattern? Which to be the other axes? What connection des exist between your question and the code you show us? In principle, you can use arrays for creating a graph... Is the column in discussion formatted as Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testChartFromPatternArray()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastECol As Long, arr, arrCh
   Dim ch As Chart, rng As Range, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row  'last row of column C:C (the one with the pattern containing "/" separator)
   lastECol = sh.cells(3, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 'last empty column calculated in the third row
   arr = sh.Range("C3:C" & lastR).value                 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   ReDim arrCh(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr)): k = 1          'redim the necessary array and initialize k variable
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If UBound(Split(arr(i, 1), "/")) = 1 Then
            arrCh(1, k) = Split(arr(i, 1), "/")(1): k = k + 1 'crete the array of numbers below the slash
        End If
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve arrCh(1 To 1, 1 To k - 1)               'redim the array prseserving only the filled elements
   sh.cells(3, lastECol).Resize(UBound(arrCh, 2), 1).value = Application.Transpose(arrCh) 'drop the array result in the first empty column
   Set rng = sh.Range(sh.cells(3, lastECol), sh.cells(k + 1, lastECol))  'create a range of the newly dropped array elements
   
   Set ch = sh.ChartObjects.Add(left:=60, top:=10, width:=300, height:=300).Chart  'create the chart
   With ch
        .Parent.Name = "Pattern Chart"  'name it
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.text = "My Pattern Chart" 'chart title
        .ChartType = xlLine             'set its type
        .SetSourceData rng              'set its data source
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i will put in your code the result

Comment: needed to appear the caption of column B and the respective result and a bar graph

Comment: @Orlando Carvalho What "result" to put in my code? Our community rules state that an answer have to be supplied to a question **as it has been formulated** and I did not see anything in your question related to the chart type and something about "a caption in the respective result", which anyhow I do not understand what you mean... When you need something else, you should place another question, but mark the answer as accepted if it answered the question. We here do not satisfy people needs, we try helping them learning and solving their issues related to a piece of code they tried...